# Program builds but displays nothing

Tags: c++

I am working on an assignment. The problem I am having is every time I try to run my program to see what it displays, nothing shows up on the command prompt. However, if I press any key and then enter, the program starts looping uncontrollably. The program doesn't even display the initial cout message, just a blinking "_". Thanks

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void PizzaMenu();
void SizePrices();
int main()
{
   double personal = 10.00;
   double medium = 14.50;
   double large = 19.00;
   double xlarge = 23.50;
   double FlavorChoice=0;
   int SizeChoice;

   int PizzaCountP=(cin >> PizzaCountP, PizzaCountP);
   int PizzaCountM = (cin >> PizzaCountM, PizzaCountM);
   int PizzaCountL = (cin >> PizzaCountL, PizzaCountL);
   int PizzaCountXL = (cin >> PizzaCountXL, PizzaCountXL);
   double orderTotal = (personal * PizzaCountP) + (medium * PizzaCountM) + (large * PizzaCountL) + (xlarge * PizzaCountXL);




   cout << "Welcome to Joes pizza place!" << endl;


   do{  
         PizzaMenu();
         cout << "\nPlease chose a pizza from the menu(1-6): ";
         cin >> FlavorChoice;

         SizePrices();
         cin >> SizeChoice;
         if (SizeChoice > 0 && SizeChoice < 5)
         {
            switch (SizeChoice)
            {

            case 1:
            cout << "How many personal pizzas? "; cin >> PizzaCountP; 
            break;
            case 2:
            cout << "How many medium pizzas?"; cin >> PizzaCountM; 
            break;
            case 3:
            cout << "How many large pizzas?"; cin >> PizzaCountL; 
            break;
            case 4: cout << "How many extra large pizzas?"; cin >> PizzaCountXL; 
            break;
            default: cout << "please enter a choice (1-4)"; cin >> SizeChoice; 
            break;
            }
         }
         if (PizzaCountP > 0 || PizzaCountM > 0 || PizzaCountXL > 0 || PizzaCountL > 0)
         {
            printf("Your total is: %a", orderTotal);
         }
    } while (FlavorChoice != 6);

    cout << "Thank you for visiting Joes place pizza! "<<endl;
}



void PizzaMenu()
{
    cout << "\nSpecialty Pizza Menu" << endl;
    cout << "\n1)Pizza 1" << endl << "\n2)Pizza 2" << endl << "\n3)Pizza 3" <<endl << "\n4)Pizza 4" << endl << "\n5)Pizza 5" << endl << "\n6)Pizza 6" << endl;
}

void SizePrices()
{
    cout << "1) 10'' Personal" << "\t" << "- $10.00" << endl;
    cout << "2) 14'' Medium" << "\t" << "- $14.50" << endl;
    cout << "3) 16'' Large" << "\t" << "- $19.00" << endl;
    cout << "4) 18'' Extra Large" << "\t" << "- $23.50" << endl;
    cout << "Your choice (1-4)? ";
 }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `int PizzaCountP=(cin >> PizzaCountP, PizzaCountP);`?

Comment: I was trying to set the value of the PizzaCountP to whatever the user entered. Thanks for pointing that out, I changed it to "= 0" and it runs, however I am having trouble displaying the orderTotal value. It keeps displaying 0 and I am not sure why.

Comment: Debugger..............

Comment: You need to move your `orderTotal` calculation to after the point you get the information from the user.

Comment: Expanding on Martin James's comment, Mike, you will learn a lot more by firing up your IDE's debugger and marching through your code than you will from almost any answer you will get here. In addition debugger use is a vital skill to the professional programmer, so working on mastering it early it time well spent.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few logical errors in the program. Right now, it should work fine...

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void PizzaMenu()
{
    cout << "Specialty Pizza Menu:" << endl;
    cout << "1) Pizza 1" << endl << "2) Pizza 2" << endl << "3) Pizza 3" << endl << "4) Pizza 4" << endl << "5) Pizza 5" << endl << "6) Exit" << endl;
}

void SizePrices()
{
    cout << "Size Prices:" << endl;
    cout << "1) 10'' Personal" << "\t" << "- $10.00" << endl;
    cout << "2) 14'' Medium" << "\t" << "- $14.50" << endl;
    cout << "3) 16'' Large" << "\t" << "- $19.00" << endl;
    cout << "4) 18'' Extra Large" << "\t" << "- $23.50" << endl;
    cout << "Your choice (1-4)? ";
}

int main()
{
    double personal = 10.00;
    double medium = 14.50;
    double large = 19.00;
    double xlarge = 23.50;
    int FlavorChoice = 0;
    int SizeChoice = 0;

    int PizzaCountP = 0;
    int PizzaCountM = 0;
    int PizzaCountL = 0;
    int PizzaCountXL = 0;
    double orderTotal = 0.0;

    cout << "Welcome to Joes pizza place!" << endl;

    cout << "Please choose from the main menu(1-6): " << endl;

    PizzaMenu();

    cin >> FlavorChoice;

    while(FlavorChoice != 6) {      

        SizePrices();

        cin >> SizeChoice;

        if (SizeChoice > 0 && SizeChoice < 5)
        {
            switch (SizeChoice)
            {

            case 1:
                cout << "How many personal pizzas? ";
                cin >> PizzaCountP;
                orderTotal += personal * PizzaCountP;
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "How many medium pizzas?";
                cin >> PizzaCountM;
                orderTotal += medium * PizzaCountM;
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "How many large pizzas?";
                cin >> PizzaCountL;
                orderTotal += large * PizzaCountL;
                break;
            case 4: cout << "How many extra large pizzas?";
                cin >> PizzaCountXL;
                orderTotal += xlarge * PizzaCountXL;
                break;
            default: cout << "please enter a choice (1-4)";
                cin >> SizeChoice;
                break;
            }
        }

        // orderTotal = (personal * PizzaCountP) + (medium * PizzaCountM) + (large * PizzaCountL) + (xlarge * PizzaCountXL);

        if (PizzaCountP > 0 || PizzaCountM > 0 || PizzaCountXL > 0 || PizzaCountL > 0)
        {
            // printf("Your total is: %a", orderTotal);
            cout << "Your total is: $" << orderTotal << endl;
        }

        cout << "Please choose from the main menu(1-6): " << endl;

        PizzaMenu();

        cin >> FlavorChoice;

    }

    cout << "Thank you for visiting Joes place pizza! " << endl;

    // system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```